# Rendering a large image containing thumbnails of multiple images?

Tags: images, thumbnails

I have a folder contains a number of images. I'd like to render a single (large) image that shows image thumbnails, along with the filename.

Can anyone recommend some good software for achieving this?

Comment: Adobe Photoshop can do this (is called "Contact sheet" function), but you haven't mentioned if it's OK with commercial software or not.

Comment: I don't have Photoshop - freeware is preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IrfanView is free and has a "contact sheet" option from the thumbnails dialog.

Comment: Thanks - perfect! Didn't know the term "Contact sheet" :-)

Comment: "Contact sheets" are copies of images on a film, printed on photo paper for a quick overview: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_print